# Is using 'exec' under controlled conditions a security threat?

Tags: python, security, exec

Here is an example class:

```
from datetime import datetime
class Article:
    published = datetime.now()
    for propname in "year month day hour minute second".split():
        exec "%s = property(lambda self: self.published.%s)"%(propname, propname)
    del propname
```

As you can see, I'm using `exec` to optimize the creation of multiple `property()` objects. I often read that using `exec` is bad and that it is a security hole in your program. In this case, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, it's not really a security threat, since the security threat arises when the executed string is something the user has any kind of access to. In this case, it is a split string literal.

However, even if it's not a security risk, `exec` is almost always a poor choice. Why not use `getattr` and `setattr` instead?

```
from datetime import datetime
class Article:
    published = datetime.now()

    def __init__(self):
        for propname in "year month day hour minute second".split():
            setattr(self, propname, getattr(self.published, propname))
```

One flaw is that this has to be done in the `__init__` method, so it depends whether you have a good reason not to include it there.

Comment: +1 for this. There is nearly always an alternative to `eval()` and `exec()`.

Comment: It can easily be done in a class decorator to add class attributes instead of instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Using *exec* with trusted data is okay; however, in this case it isn't necessary and will slow down your script.